# UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors (Deploying to WebGL)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

So I am getting this error:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002cc] in <3371b3e2e5754acd87e600e068350da5>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <3371b3e2e5754acd87e600e068350da5>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I've looked up the error on google but I am not getting any answers. The game is working just fine  in unity editor.

The error says build Player a lot so I assumed it's a compiling error in building the player. I am using the Photon Player Scripts and their scripts for game manager. (Photon Voice 2, Photon Chat, Photon Fusion, Photon Realtime)

Anyways here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject playerPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, new Vector3(Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(3f, 5f), Random.Range(-5f, 5f)), playerPrefab.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

I have 2 Scenes: "Connect&Lobby" and second scene "Main"

Also, here are some of the errors above this error (But I'm sure these aren't causing the build problems):

> Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
> Assets\Photon\PhotonVoice\Demos\DemoVoiceUI\Scripts\MicrophoneDropdownFiller.cs(110,28): error CS0103: The name 'Microphone' does not exist in the current context

I've been dealing with this issue for couple days now it's really annoying.

Also, the player script has no compiler errors pretty sure: (Take a look)

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PhotonView photonView;
    public GameObject usernameCanvas;
    public TMP_Text usernameText;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            usernameText.text = PhotonNetwork.NickName;
        }
        else
        {
            usernameText.text = photonView.Owner.NickName;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            usernameCanvas.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error `The name 'Microphone' does not exist in the current context` is the reason why you cannot build your project (at least, it is one of the reasons, perhaps, there are some more there)

According to the [unity3d documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-audio.html), `Microphone` class is not supported in WebGL.

I saw [this page](https://github.com/tgraupmann/UnityWebGLMicrophone) but didn't test it myself. Anyway, you can give it a try =)

Answer (score 0):

There is other problem with you pc or laptop some of security or vpn apps dont allow you to build your unity project just checkout your pc and build it again